# Increment variable names?

Tags: java, variables, loops, primitive

Okay so for what I am doing i need to increment my variables name, so for example
     int Taco1 = 23432.....
     int Taco2 = 234235656.....
      int Taco3 = 11111.......

But instead i need it to be a variable like

```
 int X = 0;
 some method with loop or recursion()
 int Taco(X) = bla bla bla
 x++
```

Trying to get my variable names to auto name themselves incremented by 1 every time, so they don't overwrite themselves. If this is impossible then my apologies.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do this in Java and more importantly, you don't want to do this as this isn't how Java works. In fact variable names aren't nearly as important as you think and hardly even exist in compiled code. What is much more important is that you are able to get a reference to your objects in as easy and reliable a way as possible. This can involve an array, an ArrayList  (likely what you want here), a LinkedList, a Map such as a HashMap, a Set, and other types of collections.

For example:

```
List<Taco> tacoList = new ArrayList<Taco>();
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TACOS; i++) {
   tacoList.add(new Taco(i));
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Indeed it is impossible to generate identifier names based on a variable. Perhaps what you want is an array:

```
int[] Taco = new int[ 15 /*some appropiate upper limit*/ ];

Taco[X] = bla bla bla;
```

Search the web for basic information on what arrays are and how they work.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `int[]` or a `List<Integer>`:

```
int[] tacos = new int[numberOfTacos];
// in some loop or whatever
tacos[x] = someValue;
```

Answer (score 1):

use array of `int`.  say `int taco[50]`; and you can reference each location as `taco[0]`,`taco[1]` etc

Answer (score 0):

I TacoX is going to be an integer, I would create an array of X ints. If the max number is 10, we have:

```
int[] taco = new int[10];
```

Then to modify/read tacoX, you just look at taco[X]